# Provide an alternative URL for an existing one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help. I have a page at `/register`. However, I also want to be able to view this register page at `/book-your-place-now`. I know that is possible with .htaccess but I cannot for the live of me get me head around .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite (it has to be enabled on your host)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^book\-your\-place\-now$ register [L]
```

This will make sure that if someone enters exactly `http://www.domain.com/book-your-place-now` the page `http://www.domain.com/register` will be loaded.

Comment: No need to escape the hyphens.

Comment: Good answer. I would also add that changing the `[L]` flag to `[LR]` would cause a redirect (sending the user to the '**register**' URL), which may be of some value if SEO is a concern (as duplicate content is, from what I have heard, a negative in that regard).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a .htaccess file add this

```
RewriteRule ^book-your-place-now$
register  [L]
```

If not here is what you need I believe:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteRule ^book-your-place-now$
register  [L]
```

Here is a cool little tool that I used to help me understand htaccess: [CoolTips.de .htaccess file generator](http://cooletips.de/htaccess/)

Comment: `RewriteRule` can only check the URL path but not the protocol or host. So this won’t work.

Comment: Very true, sorry my mistake. I won't worry about correcting as michal kralik answer is already correct. Still say that .htaccess site above is well worth a look for anyone learning htaccess stuff.